# Download embedded PDF on website using Selenium/Scrapy/Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

There are some pages like [this](https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmExibirArquivoIPEExterno.aspx?NumeroProtocoloEntrega=1106753) that I want to download the embedded PDF file, but researching and testing various proposed solutions on SO and other sources, I couldn't find a correct solution. When I inspect the page, I see that the PDF file is in a blob URL, and I can't save it from this URL (although I can access it through the browser). Would there be a way for me to use Selenium, Scrapy or even any other Python library to download this PDF file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open [devtools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) in your browser and go to the `network` tab and load the page you can see how the PDF file is loaded. And you can see that it's base 64 encoded.

[image: devtools]

If we search for it in the source we can find the JavaScript code, let's look at the relevant part:

```
if (document.getElementById('hdnTokenB3').value != '') {
    dataValue = "{ codigoInstituicao: '" + codInstituicao + "', numeroProtocolo: '" + numeroProtocolo + "'";
    buscarPDF(dataValue, document.getElementById('hdnTokenB3').value, '');
    return;
}
```

The id is set in the function `getParameterByName`.

```
var id = getParameterByName("ID");

if (id != null && id.length > 0) {
    var numeroProtocolo = id;
    var codInstituicao = 2;
}
else 
{
    var numeroProtocolo = getParameterByName("NumeroProtocoloEntrega");
    var codInstituicao = 1;
}
```

We can write the function in python, and then we just need to recreate the request.

```py
import scrapy
import re
import base64
import logging
import os
from urllib.parse import unquote


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example_spider"
    start_urls = ['https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmExibirArquivoIPEExterno.aspx?NumeroProtocoloEntrega=1106753']
    base_dir = './pdf_downloads'

    def parse(self, response):
        id_ = self.get_parameter_by_name("ID", response.url)

        if id_:
            numeroProtocolo = id_
            codInstituicao = 2
        else:
            numeroProtocolo = self.get_parameter_by_name("NumeroProtocoloEntrega", response.url)
            codInstituicao = 1

        dataValue = "{ codigoInstituicao: '" + str(codInstituicao) + "', numeroProtocolo: '" + str(numeroProtocolo) + "'"
        token = response.xpath('//*[@id="hdnTokenB3"]/@value').get(default='')

        versaoCaptcha = ''
        if response.xpath('//*[@id="hdnHabilitaCaptcha"]/@value').get(default='') == 'S':
            if not token:
                versaoCaptcha = 'V3'

        payload = dataValue + ", token: '" + token + "', versaoCaptcha: '" + versaoCaptcha + "'}"

        url = 'https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmExibirArquivoIPEExterno.aspx/ExibirPDF'
        headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "DNT": "1",
            "Host": "www.rad.cvm.gov.br",
            "Origin": "https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br",
            "Pragma": "no-cache",
            "Referer": f"https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmExibirArquivoIPEExterno.aspx?NumeroProtocoloEntrega={numeroProtocolo}",
            "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
            "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
            "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
        }

        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, headers=headers, body=payload, method='POST', callback=self.download_pdf, cb_kwargs={'protocol_num': numeroProtocolo})

    def download_pdf(self, response, protocol_num):
        json_data = response.json()
        b64 = json_data.get('d')

        if b64:
            pdf = base64.b64decode(b64)
            filename = f'{protocol_num}.pdf'
            p = os.path.join(self.base_dir, filename)

            if not os.path.isdir(self.base_dir):
                os.mkdir(self.base_dir)

            with open(p, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(pdf)

            self.log(f"Saved {filename} in {self.base_dir}")
        else:
            self.log("Couldn't download pdf", logging.ERROR)

    @staticmethod
    def get_parameter_by_name(name, url):
        name = name.replace('[', '\\[').replace(']', '\\]')

        results = re.search(r"[?&]" + name + r"(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)", url)
        if not results:
            return None
        if len(results.groups()) < 2 or not results[2]:
            return ''

        return unquote(results[2])
```